# Assign memory address stored in int to int

Tags: c++, c

Assuming the value of `uint32_t x` is an address. How can I get the value behind this address?
My try was to simply assign the address to a pointer.

```
int*y = x;
```

But x is not an int pointer, it's just int with an address as value.

Comment: You need to cast it. But doesn't work if you are building in 64bits and warned strongly against in modern C++ compilers with the proper flags.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is exactly for this purpose.

Comment: `int y = *(int*)x;`. Are you sure that your `uint32_t` is holding an address, though?

Comment: Read about casting (a.k.a. explicit conversion) in your favourite book. (You should be using `uintptr_t` and not assume 32-bit addresses.)

Comment: C or C++? The rules on this topic differ.

Comment: While it is true, that for portability `uintptr_t` should be used, it is often the case that the code is written for a specific (embedded) architecture, where the address is known to be 32-bit long *and* apparently might be stored in some memory / register known to be 32-bit long and thus naturally defined as `uint32_t`.

Comment: How do you get the address? What platform? Also, C or C++, answers differ...

Comment: I get the address through magic. C is actually preferable here.

Answer (score 3):

An integer type which is large enough to represent all data pointers can be converted into a pointer using `reinterpret_cast` or an explicit conversion. The pointer can be indirected to get the pointed value using the indirection operator.

Note that `uint32_t` is not guaranteed to be large enough to be able to represent all pointer values (and in fact will not be enough on modern 64 bit cpus). `uintptr_t` is meant precisely for this purpose.

Note that if the pointed address does not contain an object (of compatible type), then behaviour will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

**In C++ this can be done using `reinterpret_cast`**

> **8.5.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]**
>   ...
>   5.  A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-deﬁned. [Note: Except as described in 6.6.4.4.3, the result of such a conversion will not be a safely-derived pointer value. —end note]

**And the rules in 6.6.4.4.3 state:**

> An integer value is an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer only if its type is at least as large as `std::intptr_t` and it is one of the following:
>   —(3.1) the result of a reinterpret_cast of a safely-derived pointer value;
>   —(3.2) the result of a valid conversion of an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value;
>   —(3.3) the value of an object whose value was copied from a traceable pointer object, where at the time of the copy the source object contained an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value;
>   —(3.4) the result of an additive or bitwise operation, one of whose operands is an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value P, if that result converted by `reinterpret_cast<void*>` would compare equal to a safely-derived pointer computable from `reinterpret_cast<void*>(P)`.

So if `x` (in the question) has a type at least as large as `std::intptr_t` and is already an integral representation of a safely derived pointer as per the rules above, you will be able to get the value behind the address stored in `x`.